# Open GMail Account in browser from application with command line

Tags: email, authentication, delphi, indy, account

I have an application with a dashboard containing all my personal accoounts (emails, forums, social networks, etc). Each account is stored with its username, password, login URL, etc.

The accounts are listed on the dashboard. When I click on one of them, it opens the default browser to the login URL.

Is there a way to directly send the username and the password as command-line params with the URL to login automatically to the concerned account when opening the login page?

If yes, is it different for each service provider (Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use command-line parameters to directly instruct a browser to open a login URL and submit a username and password all at once. No browser offers command-line parameters for that purpose.

Though, you could try writing a separate script, in Python or JScript/VBScript or the like, that could be involved on a command line, and interact with a browser's DOM APIs, etc.  But this would be highly browser-specific.

And, it would not work in leau of modern security measures, like 2-factor authentication, etc.

Comment: Ok, so forget about it ! Thanks